# Spring REST throwing Exceptions to clients

Tags: java, spring, exception, rest

I have a Spring MVC based REST service. My controllers have @ExceptionHandler annotated methods for catching exceptions. I need to access the actual exception object and re-throw it to the REST client (which is Spring RestTemplate based) so the client can access the exception and its contents. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem ,and i pass current  Response Object along with Exception  and write exception content to response .I know this is not an perfect solution but i didnt find any other way supported by spring.